# kendo-drop-down-list ng-change fires twice

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-dropdown

I can't figure it out why kendo-drop-down-list ng-change fired twice as configuration done as follows,

//HTML

```
//script 
$scope.GetEditPriestSettings=function(selectedYear){
console.log($scope.EditPriestSettings);
if(selectedYear) {

angular.forEach($scope.EditPriestSettings, function (PriestSetting) {
if (parseInt(selectedYear) === parseInt(PriestSetting.Year)) {
$scope.EditPriestSetting = {
settingYear: PriestSetting.Year,
holiday: PriestSetting.HolidayDays,
seniorDays: PriestSetting.SeniorDays,
studyLeave: PriestSetting.StudyLeaveDays,
freeDays: PriestSetting.FreeDays,
redDays: PriestSetting.RedDays,
comment: PriestSetting.Comment
};
};});}};
```

what am i missing here?

Comment: please add complete code or make snippet on http://dojo.telerik.com

Comment: Kendo Angular bindings have their own events. You should be using k-on-change="myFunc()" instead of ng-change="myFunc()"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, kendo-drop-down-list ng-change is working without an issue as i have done a mistake here as i was changing model(EditPriestSetting.settingYear) in side the ng-change function (GetEditPriestSettings) and it again fired ng-change event.

```
<select kendo-drop-down-list
 ng-model="EditPriestSetting.settingYear"
 k-data-text-field="'keyDate'"
 k-data-value-field="'valueDate'"
 k-data-source="addYears"
 ng-change="GetEditPriestSettings(EditPriestSetting.settingYear)">
</select>
```